# How can I use a different database for protractor e2e tests?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, protractor, e2e-testing

I would like to use a database only for my e2e tests and do not use my development database.
I need to test the login, in this moment the test is using my development database and is not what I need, I need to create an user in the database and then test the login redirects to dashboard and displays user information
I am using node, angular, protractor and mongo.
Thanks

login.test.js

```
describe('login redirects to dashboard and displays user email', function(){
    it('should redirect to dashboard and display user email', function() {

      var email = 'john@doe.com';
      browser.get('http://localhost:3000/#/login');

      element(by.id('username')).sendKeys(email);
      element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('none123');
      element(by.id('submit-form')).click();

      expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard');
      expect(element(by.css('.username')).getText()).toEqual('Hi, ' + email);
    });
});
```

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['*.test.js']
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor doesnt which database your application is using.It will just start testing the application with the help of URL provided. If you want to test your application on different environment,then you need to create a copy of the existing application will point to a different test database and use the copied version of the application url in your protractor test.